# how to use zebra_scanner_plugin for flutter application (android)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, plugins, zebra-scanners

I'm using zebra_scanner_plugin for rfid scan for my android application. I have followed this link instruction https://pub.dev/packages/zebra_scanner_plugin (how to use section).
After doing everything. I tried to use the method

```dart
Future<void> initAndConnectScanner() async {
  try {
    await ZebraScannerPlugin.initScanner;
    await ZebraScannerPlugin.connect();
  } catch (e) {
    print("Error initializing or connecting: $e");
  }
}
```

**but once I click button to invoke this , I'm getting below error and application is crashing. I' doing something wrong ? Do I need to write java code as well ?

```
Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#zebra_scanner_plugin(18987): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.zebra.scannercontrol.DCSSDKDefs$DCSSDK_RESULT com.zebra.scannercontrol.SDKHandler.dcssdkSetDelegate(com.zebra.scannercontrol.IDcsSdkApiDelegate)' on a null object reference
E/MethodChannel#zebra_scanner_plugin(18987):    at com.androsys.zebra_scanner_plugin.ZebraScannerEngine.initialize(ZebraScannerEngine.java:52)
E/MethodChannel#zebra_scanner_plugin(18987):    at com.androsys.zebra_scanner_plugin.ZebraScannerEngine.<init>(ZebraScannerEngine.java:31)
E/MethodChannel#zebra_scanner_plugin(18987):    at com.androsys.zebra_scanner_plugin.ZebraScannerEngine.getInstance(ZebraScannerEngine.java:37)
```

Comment: Which physical Zebra device are you testing on?

Comment: Zebra Device Model: RFD8500

Comment: From what I can tell RFID needs: https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/software/developer-tools/rfid-sdk-for-android.html while normal black and white barcodes uses a different SDK lib: https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/software/developer-tools/scanner-sdk-for-android.html the Flutter package you are using is for regular b&w barcodes not RFID, https://github.com/sanketwarule/zebra_scanner_plugin/tree/master/example/android/BarcodeScannerLibrary.

Comment: okay now i have used https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/software/developer-tools/rfid-sdk-for-android.html (2.0.2.82.aar) version. still getting the same issue : Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#zebra_scanner_plugin(15645): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.zebra.scannercontrol.DCSSDKDefs$DCSSDK_RESULT com.zebra.scannercontrol.SDKHandler.dcssdkSetDelegate(com.zebra.scannercontrol.IDcsSdkApiDelegate)' on a null object reference

Comment: To my understanding the RFID SDK has a different API than regular 1-D/2-D barcodes, https://techdocs.zebra.com/dcs/rfid/android/2-0-2-94/guide/connection/ which I don't believe the Flutter plugin has. I would build/run the Java/Kotlin apps in the RFID SDK to make sure it works with device, then investigate how to make RFID SDK work with the Flutter plugin. At least raise an issue ticket with plugin author so that others are aware of the issue (or have a workaround/fix).

Comment: in any scenario, it should create the connection to the device. When I tried to console, I'm getting this: Scanner initialized successfully.
E/MethodChannel#zebra_scanner_plugin(24638): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#zebra_scanner_plugin(24638): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.zebra.scannercontrol.DCSSDKDefs$DCSSDK_RESULT com.zebra.scannercontrol.SDKHandler.dcssdkSetDelegate(com.zebra.scannercontrol.IDcsSdkApiDelegate)' 
E/MethodChannel#zebra_scanner_plugin(24638). so initScanner is working and issue is with connect()